# Application Crash on SQL Connection.Close method

Tags: c#, crash, sqlconnection, sqlconnection.close

I have a windows services which is performing lot of Data processing. At some point, my service is crashed on closing a `SQLConnection`. When I comment the Close connection method call, Service is working consistently without crashing.

What could be the problem ? Below is a code snippet

```
private void DeleteTempTable()
    {
        _logger.Info("DeleteTempTable");

        try
        {

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in _stables)
            {                 
                string dropSql = string.Empty;
                dropSql = string.Format("DROP TABLE [{0}];", item.Value);                 


                    SqlConnection oConnDropTables = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                    oConnDropTables.Open();

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dropSql))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(dropSql, oConnDropTables))
                        {                              
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                             
                        }
                    }

              if (oConnDropTables != null && oConnDropTables.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                oConnDropTables.Close();                    
                oConnDropTables = null;



            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("Error " + ex.Message);
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

When I comment the Close connection, service is working without crashing. Also it is not caught in the catch block. Also Connection is not `Null` and connectionstate is open only..

What I have tried:
 1) Put "using" construct for connection - Didn't help
 2) catching SQLException to check if anything I get- Didn't help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add the full stacktrace of the "crash" to your question. It likely contains essential information about the cause of your "crash".

Comment: opening and closing the connection in a loop....???

Comment: Define "crashed". What was the exception? What did your `_logger` report?

Comment: @codingbiz not ideal, but it shouldn't cause a crash - it'll just be talking to the pool

Comment: My services goes down basically... I am now trying debugdiag to capture dump....

Answer (score 2):

Removing that `Close()` should not make any problems go away, and frankly I don't believe it has. Since you don't yet understand the problem, it is premature to assume that a random code change has fixed it. Specifically:

- with the `Close()`, it is returning the connection to the pool each time; when you call `Open()`, it will get back the same connection from the pool (cleansed, except for a few minor things)
- without the `Close()`, the previous connection will be left to be garbage collected, which can cause either the connection-pool to become saturated, or the database-server's connection count to saturate; basically - bad things

What I *suspect* is happening is that you had some random error, that you now aren't seeing, by random. For example, network connectivity, or the unpredictable ordering of a `Dictionary<,>` (which means you don't know what order the tables are being `DROP`ped, which is ***very*** important if there are foreign keys between them).

The only major problem with the current code is that it isn't using `using`. There are some redundant lines, though. This would be better:

```
foreach (var item in _stables)
{                 
    var dropSql = string.Format("DROP TABLE [{0}];", item.Value);
    using(var oConnDropTables = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(dropSql, oConnDropTables))
    {
        oConnDropTables.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

or (preferable):

```
using(var oConnDropTables = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    oConnDropTables.Open();
    foreach (var item in _stables)
    {                 
        var dropSql = string.Format("DROP TABLE [{0}];", item.Value);
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(dropSql, oConnDropTables))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Still even after making the recommended changes app crashes at connection.close(). Also I forgot to mention that we have lot of COM calls.. Can you guess if anything that can be linked to this ??

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the creation of a new connection object each time the loop runs. When you close a SQL Connection, it is not actually closed but its returned to the app pool ready to be re-used. There is a limited number of connections you can open in SQL at once.

Try moving the SQLConnection object out of the loop and just execute commands in the loop and close the connection after the loop finishes.

```
private void DeleteTempTable()
{
    _logger.Info("DeleteTempTable");

    try
    {
        using(SqlConnection oConnDropTables = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            oConnDropTables.Open();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in _stables)
            {                 
                string dropSql = string.Empty;
                dropSql = string.Format("DROP TABLE [{0}];", item.Value);                 

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dropSql))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(dropSql, oConnDropTables))
                    {                              
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                             
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error("Error " + ex.Message);
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

Comment: I agree with the sample code (although the last two lines in the `using` are unnecessary; just let it get disposed) - however: the logic at the start does not match to the symptom. Removing the `Close()` would, at worst, cause a "timeout fetching from pool" or similar. There is no reason that *adding* the close should make it crash.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Still even after making the recommended changes app crashes at connection.close(). Also I forgot to mention that we have lot of COM calls.. Can you guess if anything that can be linked to this ??

Comment: First thing you should do is Restart the SQL Server Service. Then try running your program. If it works then my logic of filling in the app pool is correct. Then try running your program several times. If on trying it again and again this error comes back then there is somewhere in your code another connection which you are may be not closing. All this is just troubleshooting at the moment as I don't know what your other code is doing. Another way to investigate what is going on in SQL Server is to use SQL Profiler.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks. Yes you're right about close with using is redundant. I have updated the code.